# WordPress Website Content not updating

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress Site Content Not updating. Template Contents or Page or Menu not able to update any content from admin panel. only updating is- Setting/Permalink
i have change the permalink also but still not able to update anything. 
if adding a new page or post successfully added. but not able to edit.

Comment: are you using a caching plugin ?

Comment: no i am not using any caching plugin.

Comment: When i editing page contents auto redirected from admin panel to front end site.

Comment: I think you are using the mozilla firefox browser. Just try it with google chrome once and share the result here

Comment: i checked on google chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: What hosting, OS etc? Are there any rev-proxies like Varnish or Ngnix?

Comment: linux hosting.  one week before it was working. sorry for my English mistakes.

Comment: using chrome are you auto redirected from admin panel to front end site instantly or showing any other issue like "www.yourwebsiteurl.com didn’t send any data" after loading too long.

Comment: Auto redirected to front-end site. www.mysite.com not showing any error or message

Comment: I moved site to localhost and its working perfectly. why not on live server.

Answer (score 1):

Is that, the content in a post is not displayed in the front-end. Try enabling the error debug mode in wp-config file 'define('WP_DEBUG', false);' as 'define('WP_DEBUG', true);'. And check whether the post you are updating is saved.

Comment: i enabled error debug mode but. when i update redirected to home page of site. not showing any errors.

Comment: Are you using any custom post type or default WordPress post type?. Do you get success message as post updated/saved successfully.

Comment: It sounds like Varnish on front of Apache

Comment: i am using costom post type. not updating anything. i can't update menu or any theme option. after clicking on update redirected to home url of site.

Comment: Debug the issue by turning on the default theme and check for the issue. If still the issue persists, disable the custom post type you are using and check for whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: Were you able to edit/update everything before and it stopped working at some point in time? In any case, this could be a plugin issue. Since you're able to login to wp-admin, try disabling each plugin one by one and then test. If it is a plugin problem, everything should start working when you disable the offending plugin. Hope this helps.

Comment: i changed the default theme but problem not solved for me. i also checked the file permission, file permission are - files 644 and folder 755.

Comment: is this .htaccess rewrite rule issue??

Comment: if i updating widgets . when click on save the whole front end website showing that particular widget box.

Comment: I moved site to localhost and its working perfectly. why not on live server.